# Show that the collection of all rectangles $[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n, b_n]$ with $a_i,b_i$ rational can be arranged in a sequence

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can we show that the collection of all rectangles $[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n, b_n]$ with $a_i,b_i$ rational can be arranged in a sequence?

My idea is to sum the the rational end points for each of the rectangles. since the sum is rational this means that the set of the sums is a subset of the rationals but the rationals are countable this means the set of sums is countable... However my problem is how to show that for each rational the rectangles which are maped to it are finite

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Also, it seems that you have spent enough time in this community to understand how it is important to provide your own thoughts, contexts, background, etc. Please consider reformulating your question. You may also want to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: "rational can be arranged in a sequence rational can be arranged in a sequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb Q$ can be arranged in a sequence. Therefore, we can create a rectangle:

$$p_1, q_{11}, q_{12},q_{13},\dots\\ p_2, q_{21}, q_{22},q_{23},\dots\\p_3, q_{31}, q_{32},q_{33},\dots\\\vdots$$

where

1. each rational number appears as exactly one $p_i$ (i.e., for each $x\in\mathbb Q$, there exists exactly one $i$ such that $x=p_i$),
2. For each $i$, the numbers $q_{i1},q_{i2},\dots$ is a non-repeating list of all rational numbers larger than $p_i$ (i.e., for each $i$ and each $y\in \mathbb Q$ such that $y>p_i$, there exists exactly one $j$ such that $y=q_{ij}$).

Can you continue from here?

**Hint**:

For each interval $[a,b]$ with rational $a,b$, there exists exactly one pair $(i,j)$ such that $a=p_i$ and $b=q_{ij}$.

Comment: Still not quite sure how to proceed

Comment: Plus I'm not sure I understand $q_ij$ doesn't it mean$ \frac{i}{j}$ and if so how come that the sequence $ q_ij $has its numbers greater than $p_i$ where it should be the other way around...

Comment: @AbdullahO.Alfaqir No, $q_{ij}$ does **not** mean $\frac{i}{j}$. I wrote exactly what $q_{ij}$ is. I suggest you re-read my entire answer from the start.

Comment: Thank you very much...

Comment: @AbdullahO.Alfaqir If you found my answer helpful, consider accepting it so the search engine of the site can see the question was resolved.